# InvalidClassCastException in .jar after using proguard

Tags: java, android, serialization, nullpointerexception, proguard

I am using eclipse to develop an android app. When I press Run(the green triangle), the app works fine. But , I enabled proguard, and the app crashes. I am using the default proguard-android.txt which is present in sdk/tools/proguard.

I have a jar called Software.jar , which has a few classes. One of them (Data) is a serializable class.`(with serialversionUID=112358L)`. This is (probably) the part that causes the error.

This is the error log(i dont know why, but it is showing in yellow as a warning):

> 07-22 15:29:46.429: W/System.err(2051): java.io.InvalidClassException:
>   software.Data; Incompatible class (SUID): software.Data: static final
>   long serialVersionUID =112358L; but expected software.Data: static
>   final long serialVersionUID =-4551990835091843772L; 07-22
>   15:29:46.433: W/System.err(2051):     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.verifyAndInit(ObjectInputStream.java:2380)
>   07-22 15:29:46.433: W/System.err(2051):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1662)
>   07-22 15:29:46.437: W/System.err(2051):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:683)
>   07-22 15:29:46.437: W/System.err(2051):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1803)
>   07-22 15:29:46.441: W/System.err(2051):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
>   07-22 15:29:46.441: W/System.err(2051):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
>   07-22 15:29:46.441: W/System.err(2051):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
>   07-22 15:29:46.445: W/System.err(2051):   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:657) 07-22 15:29:46.445:
>   W/System.err(2051):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) 07-22 15:29:46.449: W/System.err(2051):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-22 15:29:46.449:
>   W/System.err(2051):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
>   07-22 15:29:46.449: W/System.err(2051):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
>   07-22 15:29:46.453: W/System.err(2051):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
>   07-22 15:29:46.453: W/System.err(2051):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
>   07-22 15:29:46.457: W/System.err(2051):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
>   07-22 15:29:46.457: W/System.err(2051):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
>   07-22 15:29:46.457: W/System.err(2051):   at
>   com.mainpackage.FullGenPhysics.a(Unknown Source) 07-22 15:29:46.457:
>   W/System.err(2051):   at com.mainpackage.de.run(Unknown Source)

and these are the red lines(tag error)

> 07-22 15:29:46.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2051): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   Thread-161 07-22 15:29:46.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 07-22 15:29:46.465:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2051):   at software.Gen_Phy.a(Unknown Source) 07-22
>   15:29:46.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at software.Gen_Phy.a(Unknown
>   Source) 07-22 15:29:46.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):   at
>   software.Gen_Phy.(Unknown Source) 07-22 15:29:46.465:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2051):   at com.mainpackage.FullGenPhysics.a(Unknown
>   Source) 07-22 15:29:46.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):   at
>   com.mainpackage.de.run(Unknown Source) 07-22 15:29:46.465:
>   W/ActivityManager(333):   Force finishing activity
>   com.mainpackage/.FullGenPhysics 07-22 15:29:46.525:
>   E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152
>   07-22 15:29:46.525: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for
>   354288 bytes, got 16384  07-22 15:29:46.529: E/SocketStream(112):
>   readFully was waiting for 337904 bytes, got 1624  07-22 15:29:46.529:
>   E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 336280 bytes, got 49152
>   07-22 15:29:46.533: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for
>   287128 bytes, got 16384  07-22 15:29:46.533: E/SocketStream(112):
>   readFully was waiting for 270744 bytes, got 1624  07-22 15:29:46.537:
>   E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 269120 bytes, got 49152
>   07-22 15:29:46.537: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for
>   219968 bytes, got 16384  07-22 15:29:46.537: E/SocketStream(112):
>   readFully was waiting for 203584 bytes, got 1624  07-22 15:29:46.541:
>   E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 201960 bytes, got 49152
>   07-22 15:29:46.541: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for
>   152808 bytes, got 16384  07-22 15:29:46.541: E/SocketStream(112):
>   readFully was waiting for 136424 bytes, got 1624  07-22 15:29:46.545:
>   E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 134800 bytes, got 49152
>   07-22 15:29:46.545: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for
>   85648 bytes, got 16384  07-22 15:29:46.549: E/SocketStream(112):
>   readFully was waiting for 69264 bytes, got 1624  07-22 15:29:46.549:
>   E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 67640 bytes, got 49152 
>   07-22 15:29:46.549: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for
>   18488 bytes, got 16384

The funny thing is, that I have a system.out in one of the classes of software.jar. That is getting printed.

I have tried adding `-libraryjars C:\Users\Harsh\git\marks++\Marks++\Software.jar` as well as

```
-keep  class Software.**
```

to the already mentioned .txt file

Where am I going wrong ?

**EDIT**

> ```
> 07-22 16:10:54.957: W/System.err(2233): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: software.Data
> 07-22 16:10:54.961: W/System.err(2233):   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
> 07-22 16:10:54.961: W/System.err(2233):   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
> 07-22 16:10:54.965: W/System.err(2233):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2301)
> 07-22 16:10:54.965: W/System.err(2233):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1660)
> 07-22 16:10:54.965: W/System.err(2233):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:683)
> 07-22 16:10:54.969: W/System.err(2233):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1803)
> 07-22 16:10:54.969: W/System.err(2233):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
> 07-22 16:10:54.973: W/System.err(2233):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
> 07-22 16:10:54.973: W/System.err(2233):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
> 07-22 16:10:54.973: W/System.err(2233):   at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:657)
> 07-22 16:10:54.973: W/System.err(2233):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 07-22 16:10:54.977: W/System.err(2233):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> 07-22 16:10:54.977: W/System.err(2233):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
> 07-22 16:10:54.977: W/System.err(2233):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
> 07-22 16:10:54.977: W/System.err(2233):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
> 07-22 16:10:54.977: W/System.err(2233):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
> 07-22 16:10:54.977: W/System.err(2233):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
> 07-22 16:10:54.977: W/System.err(2233):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
> 07-22 16:10:54.977: W/System.err(2233):   at com.mainpackage.FullGenPhysics.a(Unknown Source)
> 07-22 16:10:54.977: W/System.err(2233):   at com.mainpackage.de.run(Unknown Source)
> 07-22 16:10:54.981: W/System.err(2233): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/Data
> 07-22 16:10:54.981: W/System.err(2233):   ... 20 more
> 07-22 16:10:54.981: W/System.err(2233): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: software.Data
> 07-22 16:10:54.981: W/System.err(2233):   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
> 07-22 16:10:54.981: W/System.err(2233):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
> 07-22 16:10:54.981: W/System.err(2233):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
> 07-22 16:10:54.985: W/System.err(2233):   ... 20 more
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems after going through `proguard` your `serializable` class's `serialVersionUID` is getting changed. You need to change the `configuration of proguard` to include:

```
-keepclassmembers class software.Data {
    static final long serialVersionUID;

}
```

As described [Here](http://littlepancake.com/2011/09/proguard-and-serialized-java-objects/)

Comment: i am getting classnotfoundexception now

Comment: Please post stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution after a bit of experimenting.
This is what I used:

```
-libraryjars Software.jar
-keep  class software.**{
*;

}
```